# Django: How to relate a template form to each object is a list and use that specific request to remove that object from the list?

Tags: python, django, templates, view, model

I have a ManyToMany field called `available_player` in a `League` model that contains all the players in a baseball league. In my `draft.html` template I am using a `for` loop to list each player as well as a draft `button` next to each. I am trying to make a fantasy baseball league, so when a player is drafted and the form is submitted, the specific player needs to be removed from the `available_players`.
(The list of `available_players` comes from a `Player` model that has all the player names, their positions, and teams).

models.py:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class League(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    conference = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CONF_CHOICES, default='south')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='members')
    draft_date_and_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True, help_text='YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm (24 hour time)')

    available_player = models.ManyToManyField(Player)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

draft.html:

```
{% for player in players %}
  <div class="row mb-5 pt-4 pb-3 border border-success rounded-lg" style="background-color: rgb(70,70,70);">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          {{ player.team}}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          {{ player }}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          {{ player.position }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col text-right">
    <button class="button is-info">Add to pending</button>
      <form method="post" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!--Need each button to relate to a specific player in views.py-->
        <button class="button is-success">Draft</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
def draft(request, league_id, league_title):
    south_conf = ['Chemeketa','Clackamas','Clark','Lane','Linn-Benton','Mt Hood','SW Oregon','Umpqua']
    league = League.objects.get(id=league_id)
    players = Player.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST': # Receive post request from template and delete specific player from League.available_player
        league = League.objects.get(id=league_id)
        for player in league.available_player.all():
            print(player)
      
    context = {'league': league, 'players': players, 'south_conf': south_conf}

    return render(request, 'league/draft.html', context)
```

I think this could be achieved by giving each `form` in the for loop a specific id that relates to the player, but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

I made the 'players' dictionary in view 'draft', which is passed to the template context. The loop in the template creates buttons based on this dictionary, with a value at each iteration: value={{player}}. The result is returned to the same view.
In which, depending on which button is pressed, the result is displayed in print:

```
print(request.POST.get('bbb'))
```

**In the line 'bboard/draft.html', replace bboard with the name of your folder where the templates are located. I have it templates/bboard.**

views.py

```
def draft(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST.get('bbb'))

    context = {'players': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}

    return render(request, 'bboard/draft.html', context)
```

templates(draft.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Your form</h2>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'draft'%}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for player in players %}
        <button class="button is-success" name='bbb' value={{ player }}>player {{ player }}</button><br>
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("draft/", draft, name="draft"),
]
```